# Split audio into every 10% of the audio length in python

Tags: python, audio, split

I have 10 audio files (*.wav). Each audio's starting time is 0, and end time varies. I want to normalize all the audio files and make the audio length the same, i.e., 1. So, audio starts from 0 and ends at 1. Then, I want to divide the audio into chunks where each chunk is 10%. For example, start is 0%,0.01-0.10 means 10%, 0.11-0.20 means 20%,.... and so on. I want to save each splitted audio files in a folder. How should I do it in python?

I have tried looking solutions, mostly based on timestamps, nothing matches the way I wanted.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.